# Sending paramaters to async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

How can I pass data into an async function? I'm trying to get the Google search result and pass it into puppeteer to open the page.

```
google('example.com test', function (err, res){
  if (err) console.error(err)

  var link = res.links[0].link.toString();
  console.log(res.links[0].link)

});

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(link, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

  const m = page.mouse
  await m.click(110,420)

  browser.on('targetcreated',  pageOpened => {
      console.log('1');
  });
  await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});
  let url = await page.url()
  console.log(url)
  fs.appendFile('saved.txt', url, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
  });

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just promisify the google call:

```
 const link = new Promise(resolve => {
  google('example.com test', (err, res) => {
    if(err) {
       console.error(err);
       return;
    }
    resolve(res.links[0].link.toString());  
  });
 });
```

Then inside your async function just do

```
 await link
```

to use the link somewhere.